# sbt test hangs on 'Running TaskDef'

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm trying to run a simple fibonacci problem with unit tests from a scala tutorial. it has been working but suddently stopped & I don't know why- specifically it hangs at 'running taskdef' when using `sbt debug test`. The directory structure `src/test/scala/TestFile.scala` is correct, as is the path for `main` files. `sbt clean` hasn't helped, but git checkouting an old branch which worked and then rewriting my updates did work for a time- then stopped.

one other concern is that i have accidentally run `sbt test` from outside the root directory once or twice. not sure if that could have created some extra cruft that is messing this up.

thanks.

updating with my code:
fib/build.sbt: (from an exercism.io problem i used as a template)

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"
```

but i think i've narrowed it down to my main file below. I refactored and suddenly my tests worked again. I committed, checked out my old code (which i was trying to break on purpose to verify my tests were running) and tests weren't working again. I checked out this file from HEAD and they ran once again.

fib/src/main/scala/Fibonacci.scala: (the version from `0d4d` below)

```
object Fibonacci {
  def fib(nth: Int): Int = {

    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(nth: Int, acc: List[Int] = List[Int](1, 0)): Int = {
      if (nth == 1) 0
      else if (nth == 2) 1
      else {
        val newFibs = acc(0) + acc(1) :: acc
        if (newFibs.length == nth) newFibs(0) else go(nth, newFibs)
      }
    }
    go(nth)
  }
}

$ git checkout 0d4d
HEAD is now at 0d4d93d...
$ sbt test
[info] Set current project to fib (in build file:~/dev/courses/fp-in-scala/sbts/fib/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to ~/dev/courses/fp-in-scala/sbts/fib/target/scala-2.10/classes...
 { hangs }

$ git checkout master -- src/main/scala/Fibonacci.scala
$ sbt test
{ tests work }
$ git checkout 0d4d -- src/main/scala/Fibonacci.scala
$ sbt test
[info] Set current project to fib (in build file:~/dev/courses/fp-in-scala/sbts/fib/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to ~/dev/courses/fp-in-scala/sbts/fib/target/scala-2.10/classes...
{ hangs }
```

Comment: can you post your build definition and all your code? hard to say what it is without trying to replicate it locally

Comment: try "git clean -df" it will clean any directories that are not explicitly tracked by git. You can also try to manually delete all target folders you have and run it again.

Comment: hmmm, yeah- i was actually wondering if deleting my target folders could have been the start of the problem. done git clean and deleted, same problem. will update with my code.